# SSL certificate wildcard / single name - will it work for subdirectories?

Tags: security-certificate

I want to purchase an SSL certificate for my domain, but I have never worked with certificates.

I will purchase it at DNSimple, my APP is on heroku and my domain is at all-inkl.

Will the wildcard certificate also cover all subdirectories (These are generated by my python flask app and are shown as URLs):

for example: `www.example.com` (root) and `www.example.com/sub` and `www.example.com/sub/test`

Comment: What you've shown in your example is a _sudirectory_, not a _subdomain_?

Comment: These are the URL names which my flask python app generates

Comment: But I am currently reading an article about subdomains / subdirectories. It seems I use the wrong terms. A wildcard will not secure subdirecotries?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't need a "wildcard" certificate to secure *subdirectories*. All SSL certs will secure subdirectories. SSL certs secure *hosts* (domains). A "wildcard cert" will ordinarily secure *subdomains* eg. `<anysubdomain>.example.com` - but this should be made clear when you purchase the cert.

Comment: Also, check out the Lets Encrypt project for a free SSL cert.

Comment: Thank you very much! Will a single name cover both versions: www.mysite.com and mysite.com? Or is this handled in the DNS settings?

Comment: @Yhorian Yeah I was playing for a long time with that. Its comlicated for apps on heroku and an external domain. Plus it does not have windows servers yet. I use letsencrypt on simple websites.

Comment: Yes, a single named cert will _usually_ cover both www and non-www versions these days (hasn't always been the case) - but again, double check this when buying the cert. (This isn't a DNS thing.)

Answer (score 6):

Wildcard SSL certificates are used to secure sub-domains.

For example,

- mail.example.com
- shop.example.com
- anysub.example.com

You can install any single domain SSL certificate on your website, it can secure your root domain as well all directories / folders.

For example,

- example.com/your-product-name
- example.com/discount-offer-page
- example.com/any-web-pages

Comment: What does this add that the other answer does not?

Comment: @cybermonkey I can't speak for Jason but IMO this answer is simpler.

Comment: I find the examples useful.

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned, you are wishing to secure your sub-directories. When you install any SSL certificate on your server, it secures `example.com` and all its sub-directories.

Which means not only `example.com` displays with HTTPS but sub-directories also display with HTTPS.

- Website before SSL Certificate - `http://example.com`
- Website After HTTPS - `https://example.com`
- website sub-directory before SSL certificate - `http://example.com/sub-directory`
- Website sub-directory after SSL certificate - `https://example.com/sub-directory`

A Wildcard SSL certificate, on the otherhand, is aimed to secure unlimited sub-domains, but for sub-directories (as I've mentioned above) a single **Domain-Validated (DV) SSL** certificate will work fine.